# how to remove a whitespace in a list in python?

Tags: python

I'm new here so forgive me if there's anything unusual
I know it's simple to remove some whitespaces
but actually I'm not using strings, it's float elements list
so I'm using append to put the numbers in the list but they are passed in like this:

```
[1.2, 3.5, 41.2, 2.9]
```

I want them to be like this:

```
[1.2,3.5,41.2,2.9]
```

any kind of help will appreciated

Comment: Both are the same thing though?

Comment: There is no actual whitespace. It is just a representation.

Comment: no actually the first one got spaces after the comma

Comment: If its a list of integers/floats there is no spacing in the list, it shows it like that to make it nicer to view. If you iterate the list you will only get numbers.

Comment: As @mad_ said, that is only a representation of the list, the numbers are not saved with white spaces. It is only printed this way for visibility.

Comment: Use str.replace() to replace the whitespaces with nothing when you print.

Comment: im storing the numbers in a file so if the file been read again the spaces will be there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no actual whitespace in the list. It is just how it's `__str__` function is coded (the way it prints out). If you want to print it out without any spaces the best way to do it is convert it to a string first:

```
>>> test = [2, 32, 123, 1]
>>> test
[2, 32, 123, 1]
>>> print(str(test).replace(" ",""))
[2,32,123,1]
```

Answer (score 1):

Both those list representations are equal, regardless of the whitespace added after the commas. The extra whitespace just makes it clearer to read.

To really test if they are equal, you can use `==` comparison:

```
>>> l1 = [1.2, 3.5, 41.2, 2.9]
>>> l2 = [1.2,3.5,41.2,2.9]
>>> l1 == l2
True
```

If you want a string representation without whitespace, you can use [`str.join()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join):

```
>>> l1 = [1.2, 3.5, 41.2, 2.9]
>>> '[%s]' % ','.join(map(str, l1))
'[1.2,3.5,41.2,2.9]'
```

Answer (score 0):

That is the default behavior of Python's `__str__` but hey its Python and you can override the default behavior. I will not recommend to change the default code of `__str__` but instead write your own `list` like class of yours to meet the requirement of yours

```
class my_list(list):
    x=[]
    def __init__(self, argument):
        self.x=list(argument)

    def __str__(self):
        return '['+','.join(map(str,self.x))+']'
```

For testing

```
print(my_list([1.2, 3.5, 41.2, 2.9]))   #[1.2,3.5,41.2,2.9,5,6]
```